# client side conditional validators rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, client-side-validation

I have the following model validation

```
validates_numericality_of :resident_mof_value, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 100, :allow_nil => true, if: Proc.new { |r| r.resident_yrs.present? }
validates_numericality_of :resident_yrs, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 1, :less_than_or_equal_to => 99, :allow_nil => true, if: Proc.new { |r| r.resident_mof_value.present? }
```

But this is model validation. The current client side validation gem doesnt allow for conditional validators to be triggered on the client side so this conditional validators do not work on client side.

Is there any way to be able to trigger these conditional validators client side?

The documentation in the gem says to do something like this

```
<%= f.text_field :name, validate: { presence: true } %>
```

But that is easy if the validation is something like `presence: true` but if it is a condition such as mine, how do i get it to work?

I can do this using pure jquery or javascript just asking how it can be implemented using the client side validation gem with rails

Comment: From [`client_side_validation`'s Project Goals: 3rd pointer](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations#project-goals), I quote "In the cases where a server-side validation rule would not work on the client (i.e. conditional callbacks like :if, :unless) then do not attempt client side validations. Fall back to the server side validation." Reason is that the client-side is completely already disconnected from the server once the page already loads the JS (that includes your client-side validations), therefore if your...

Comment: `if` condition--let's say just `validates ... if: { User.count > 1 }`--is accessing the database (like this example), then your JS-client-side should also be accessing the database, and in just this simple example it's not gonna work because of the nature of request-response one-way communication from the server to the client-side. It is still possible in the future (by auto dispatching some AJAX requests to execute the condition or to make the `if` condition completely back-end), however implementing this is going to be difficult or takes a lot of time, and probably also prone to bugs.

Comment: As I have said in my previous comment, if you're fine with the `if` condition being executed only in the backend, then you'd not be able to use the `client_side_validations` gem, but I can write up a possible workaround using AJAX requests to call an endpoint: i.e. `POST /validations/MODEL_NAME` each time you want to validate the form (i.e. when you remove focus on a text field), and then display the validation errors (if any) immediately automatically. This is very inefficient and expensive, but this will handle all your "conditional" logic.